# WKT and openlayers

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers, wkt

I cant find out how to use the `WKT` format in OpenLayers.

I have tried finding the [solution in the documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.6/examples/wkt.html), witch bascily brought me to this:  http://jsfiddle.net/Christer/WG8YP/2/

But that gives me the error of :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

I have no clue about what the hazzle is about, as the numbers and everything are copied straight out of openlayers own bounds/points/geo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/WG8YP/4/

`addFeatures` takes an [array of features](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.addFeatures).

## Code:

```js
var polygonFeature = wkt.read("POLYGON((-15.8203125 2.4609375, -15.8203125 -10.546875, 6.85546875 -11.25, 8.26171875 -3.33984375, -15.8203125 2.4609375))");
polygonFeature.geometry.transform(map.displayProjection, map.getProjectionObject());         
vectors.addFeatures([polygonFeature]);
```

Comment: Thanks alot man ! Made my day - Didnt know that it took a string! As for the array, i did try that aswell - but as your example shows, _wkt.read_ thakes a string.